# How to add a shortcut to the 'SendTo' menu that will be available to all users

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-shell

You can add a new item to the 'Send To' Windows explorer menu by creating an application shortcut in the SendTo folder contained in the user's profile folder e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\Username\SendTo\

But how do you add a 'Send To' menu item that will be available to all users without having to add it to every user's profile folder?

I found one page that suggested that you could create a SendTo folder in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users but the article was targeted at Windows 2000 and it does not appear to work in Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think AllUsers works for SendTo.

But you might add it to the DefaultUser SendTo folder. Then any *new* users would inherit a copy of the shortcut in their SendTo folder.

If you're wanting to add it to existing users, you're stuck putting the shortcuts in individual user's SendTo folders.

Comment: But how do you make the shortcuts point to the right SendTo folders?